# How to encode and stream a video from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, video-capture, video-encoding

I'm capturing CGImageRef frames using UIGetScreenImage() on an iPhone 3GS 3.1.3 and want to stream this over the interwebs in any appropriate, well known format.

What video codec libraries are available that would allow me to encode the raw pixel data into a video? (i'm not too familiar with video codecs, but am familiar with network programming to actually send the data out)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend encoding on the client. Have the video available on the server already encoded and use MPMoviePlayerController to present it:

good tutorial on how to stream video:

http://buildmobilesoftware.com/2010/08/09/how-to-stream-videos-on-the-iphone-or-ipad/

Comment: So you're saying I should send it uncompressed to a server that will encode it for me? Again, my question would be, in what format do I stream it to the server?